# Error while installing tweepy on windows

Tags: python, tweepy

I am installing Tweepy on my windows machine from command prompt using this "python setup.py install" and I am getting follwing error.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aLQjJ.png)

I have no idea about this error. Please help me out.

Thanks Shraddha.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install [requests-oauthlib](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/requests-oauthlib). You can either do that with `pip install requests requests_oauthlib` as suggested on the package page or by downloading and installing the package files yourself.

Answer (score 0):

```
pip install tweepy
```

will solve your problem i guess. when you run cmd as an Administrator and then type `pip install tweepy` and run it , it will allow you to import modules such as Stream , OAuthHandler and StreamListener from tweepy package . it has solved and worked for me when i got same error.